# Finding the row with max separation between elements of an array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array of size m x n. Each row has n elements which shows some probability (between 0 and 1). I want to find the row which has the max difference between its elements while it would be better if its nonzero elements are greater as well.

For example in array Arr:

```
Arr = [0.1   0     0.33   0     0.55  0;
       0.01  0     0.10   0     0.2   0;
       1     0.1   0      0     0     0;
       0.55  0     0.33   0     0.15  0;
       0.17  0.17  0.17   0.17  0.17  0.17]
```

the best row would be 3rd row, because it has more distinct values with greater values. How can I compute this using Matlab?

Comment: That's a very vague question. What are the criteria for choosing the "best" row? Are you searching the row with the maximum differencde between any two elements, or between adjacent elements? Or are you trying to average the differences somehow? Also, how do you include the "non-zero" elements into consideration, _i.e_ how do you prioritize that?

Comment: I want maximum difference between any two elements of an array not only the adjacent ones or etc. Also non-zero elements are considered the same as the others, the less alike the elements the better, ergo a row with 3 zero and 3 non-zero but close values is worse than a row with 4 zeros and 2 very different values. In another words each element is a pre-defined probability of a different category, so the row which has very different probabilities for different categories is better than one which only discriminates 1 category from other 5 categories in the example. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you're looking for the row with the greatest [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation), which is basically a measure of how much the values vary from the average.

If you want to ignore zero elements, use Shai's useful suggestion to replace zero elements to `NaN`. Indeed, some of MATLAB's built-in functions allow ignoring them:

```
Arr2 = Arr;
Arr2(~Arr) = NaN;
```

To find the standard deviation we'll employ [`nanstd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanstd.html) (not `std`, because it doesn't ignore `NaN` values) along the rows, *i.e.* the 2<sup>nd</sup> dimension:

```
nanstd(Arr2, 0, 2)
```

To find the greatest standard deviation and it's corresponding row index, we'll apply [`nanmax`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmax.html) and obtain both output variables:

```
[stdmax, idx] = nanmax(nanstd(Arr2, 0, 2));
```

Now `idx` holds hold the index of the desired row.

#### Example

Let's run this code on the input that you provided in your question:

```
Arr = [0.1   0     0.33   0     0.55  0;
       0.01  0     0.10   0     0.2   0;
       1     0.1   0      0     0     0;
       0.55  0     0.33   0     0.15  0;
       0.17  0.17  0.17   0.17  0.17  0.17];

Arr2 = Arr;
Arr2(~Arr) = NaN;
[maxstd, idx] = nanmax(nanstd(Arr2, 0, 2))

idx =
    3
```

Note that the values in row #3 differ one from another much more than those in row #1, and therefore the standard deviation of row #3 is greater. This also corresponds to your comment:

> *... ergo a row with 3 zero and 3 non-zero but close values is worse than a row with 4 zeros and 2 very different values.*

For this reason I believe that in this case `3` is indeed the correct answer.

Comment: You might want to use `nanmax` for finding the max of `nanstd`: If you happen to have a row with only zerosm `nanstd` returns `NaN`...

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you wish to ignore `0`s in your matrix. You may achieve this by setting them to `NaN` and proceed using special build-in functions that ignore `NaN`s (e.g., `nanmin`, `nanmax`, etc.)

Here is a sample code for finding the row (`ri`) with the largest difference between minimal (nonzero) response and the maximal response:

```
nArr = Arr;
nArr( Arr == 0 ) = NaN; % replace zeros with NaNs
mn = nanmin(nArr, [], 2); % find minimal, non zero response at each row
mx = nanmax(nArr, [], 2); % maximal response
[~, ri] = nanmax( mx - mn ); % fid the row with maximal difference
```